# Brocade XMR randomly losing virtual interface IP address

Tags: interface, brocade

We have a pair of XMR routers configured 100+ VLANs running VSRP downstream and BGP upstream.  At random times, the IP information is deleted and I have to go in and reset it.

Each VLAN config looks something like this.

```
interface ve 99
 ip ospf area 0.0.0.0
 ip ospf passive
 ip address 1.2.3.4/27

vlan 99 name ClientName
 tagged e 1/9 e 2/9
 router-interface ve 99

interface ethernet 1/9
 enable
 no route-only

interface ethernet 2/9
 enable
 no route-only
```

Once every 1 to 8 months, we lose the "interface ve" IP address.

```
#show interface ve 99
Ve99 is up, line protocol is down
  Type is Vlan (Vlan Id: 99)
  Hardware is Virtual Ethernet, address is 000c.xxxx.xxxx (bia 000c.xxxx.xxxx)
  No port name
  Vlan id: 99
  Internet address is 0.0.0.0/0, IP MTU 1500 bytes, encapsulation ethernet
```

When this happens I'm unable to ping 1.2.3.4 from anywhere including localhost.

To fix it I do:

```
#no interface ve 99
#interface ve 99
#ip ospf area 0.0.0.0
#ip ospf passive
#ip address 1.2.3.4/27
```

That fixes it immediately.

```
#show interface ve 99
Ve99 is up, line protocol is up
  Type is Vlan (Vlan Id: 99)
  Hardware is Virtual Ethernet, address is 000c.xxxx.xxxx (bia 000c.xxxx.xxxx)
  No port name
  Vlan id: 99
  Internet address is 1.2.3.4/27, IP MTU 1500 bytes, encapsulation ethernet
```

But why does it get zeroed out like that?  Is this a hardware issue with memory corruption?  Rare software bug?  Or it this a state that can be entered by design during particular network condition?

There is nothing useful in the log during this event.  But is there a way to increase verbosity of the event log on a long term basis? (remember sometimes this doesn't happen for months at a time)

Comment: Have you checked whether this coincides with a reboot? Maybe the config just isn't saved permanently... What does the log show?

Comment: There is no reboot when this happens.  Boot config shows the IP is present.   I wish I had a chance to compare running config with boot config when this happened, but it's now fixed so I can't go back to check.  I did check the boot config and it is fine.   Logs don't show anything unusual like reboots, errors or warnings during the event, just the same routine entries like any other day.